# Objective-C JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Tags: ios, json, xml

I am trying to get XML From a web services doing the following:

```
NSString *areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters = [areaDescription componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters = [areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?areaDescriptionPLXml=%@",kIP,areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters];
    NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];

    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    if(data == nil)
        return nil;
    NSError *myError;
    NSDictionary *punchList = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];
```

but I get this error:

```
[0] (null)  @"NSDebugDescription" : @"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." for `myError`
```

Here is my XML:

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89>
  <KeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89>
    <Key>ORC0023</Key>
    <Value>
      <baseOrSchedStartList>
        <string>2015-09-11T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-08-10T16:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-08-11T16:00:00</string>
       </baseOrSchedStartList>
    </Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't parse XML with a JSON parser

Comment: You do realize you can't parse XML as JSON, right?  You'll need to use something like `NSXMLParser` (or I suppose a third-party library) instead of `NSJSONSerialization` to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML is... an XML. Not a JSON.

Try using a 3rd party such as this:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

for XML parsing.